# Acessing Current Batch Size (on per batches per epoch)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer

I'm working on a keras layer based on the [_Merge Layer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.14.0/keras/layers/merging/base_merge.py) and the idea is to perform a comparasion element-wise between 3 variables and change the value of x based on a certain conditon function of a_11 and a_22. So far I've come this far using [tf.tensor_scatter_nd_min](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_min)/[max](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_max) to search the multiple scenarios where the value of x must be limited and force it.

My issue lies in the `batch_size` variable which the way I set it up (very poorly) fails when the last batch is reached as it has a slighly smaller size compared to the others but the way the code is structured it just receives the initial batch_size...

So what I am really asking is how can I acess the "the batch size of the current step" and if there is a better way to tackle this problem without having to pass all indices to tf.tensor_scatter_nd_min/max?

**P.S.** I did try with Sparse Tensors but had no luck either

```py
from keras.layers.merging.base_merge import _Merge

class _realize_12(_Merge):    
    def __init__(self, BATCH):
        super(_realize_12, self).__init__()
        self.batch_size = BATCH
    
    def _merge_function(self, inputs):        
        a_11 = inputs[0]
        x = inputs[1]
        a_22 = inputs[2]
        
        limit = tf.math.sqrt((tf.math.abs(a_11)+1/3)*(tf.math.abs(a_22)+1/3)) 
        
        _all =  [[i] for i in range(self.batch_size)]
                              
        return tf.tensor_scatter_nd_min(tf.tensor_scatter_nd_max(x, _all, -limit), _all, limit, name='constrain_a_12')
```